# Spring Hibernate won't implement Repository Class from Interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two separate projects. One project contains my Application logic and Controllers in `org.patrick.application`, and one separate project contains my Hibernate entities, Dao, and models in `org.patrick.hibernate`. My problem is that Spring will not instantiate a implementing class for my `CrudRepository`.

Here is my `Application.java` class annotations in my Application project:

```
package org.patrick.application;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "org.patrick.hibernate" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "org.patrick.hibernate" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.patrick.hibernate", "org.patrick.application" })
```

These annotations should scan my second Hibernate project for all of my Hibernate objects.

My Hibernate repository looks like this:

```
package org.patrick.hibernate;

@Repository
public interface PatrickDao extends CrudRepository<MyModel, Long>
```

This repository does not have a class implementation. I am expecting Spring to populate this implementation for me.

Now, inside of my application `org.patrick.application`, I am trying to use the Dao like so:

```
package org.patrick.application;

@Autowired
private PatrickDao patrickDao;
```

This is causing my Application project to fail to start because of the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [org.patrick.hibernate.PatrickDao]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

I know that the core problem is that Spring is not implementing this interface -
 because if I provide my own `PatrickDaoImpl` in the `org.patrick.hibernate` package, then the Application project will start just fine. This confuses me because I have the proper annotations on my `Application.java` class, and yet the Repository cannot be implemented by Spring for some reason.

Is there anything further I need to do in order to get Spring to implement the class for my Repository interface? In previous testing, this behavior works if everything is under the same package.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce this behavior.  Would you mind sharing a minimal example project on GitHub?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you added `@EnableJpaRepositories` & `@EntityScan` to your hibernate application?

Comment: Kyle: My two projects are different applications, with the first Application project importing the second project via a Maven dependency. Would this change the equation at all?

Comment: Luay: No, I have not. The Hibernate application is just a library containing Models, Entities, and Repositories. It is meant to just be a resource to be imported by the actual application. Are you saying I should have those `EnableJpaRepositories` and `EntityScan` annotations in this resource library as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. For this particular Model, the definition looked as such:

```
package org.patrick.hibernate;

public class MyModel implements Serializable {}
```

This Model did not have the `@Entity` annotation. If this annotation is missing, then Spring will give no warnings as to why it cannot implement the repository interface. In my case, it simply threw the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` exception.

I updated my Model with the proper annotations:

```
package org.patrick.hibernate;

@Entity
public class MyModel implements Serializable {}
```